# Magento-2 : How to set admin form data by join tables

Tags: magento2, customer, join-table

I have a custom admin module which store customer related data. My custom table created foreign key with **customer_id**.

I displayed customer name, email in my module grid by join query, It's working but how to set data to edit action by join query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have completed by add below function to Model Resource

```
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

    $select->joinLeft(
        array('t_b' => 'table_b'),
        $this->getMainTable() . '.id = t_b.id',
        array('columnA'));
    return $select;
}
```